# What is the correct way to pass the Google API parameter "latlng=40.714224,-73.961452" in Uri.https?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to make a Uri to query the google API and return an address. I need to create a Uri to generate the url:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY

In my code I did like this:

```
  final url = https.Uri(
    'maps.googleapis.com'
    'maps/api/geocode/json',
    {
      'latlng': '${position.latitude},${position.longitude}',
      'key': myGoogleKeyApi,
    },
  );
```

The generated url works, but since I'm new to dart, I would like to know if using Uri to generate the url from query Parameters 'latlng' is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You mean `Uri.https`, not `https.Uri`.  Otherwise what you have should be fine.